# Change recyclerView scroll position reference

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

Is there a way to change the scroll counter reference of recyclerView to start from the center of the screen, and not from the beginning?
So that, when I call linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() I get the position of the item in the screen center and not at the start of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough! but I think `clipToPadding = true` and `paddingBottom` can solve your problem with recyclerView I understood your problem correctly

Comment: I am using recyclerView with horizontal layoutManager, and calling findFirstVisibleItemPosition() to return the first visible item, but I need a way to get the item at the middle of the screen.

Comment: So you have lastVisiablePosition via findLastVisibleItemPosition(), the middle item position is depend on your logic

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for this issue, I simply override getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingEnd() methods as below.

```
private fun setupLinearManager(context: Context) {
    linearLayoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(context, HORIZONTAL, false) {

        override fun getPaddingLeft(): Int {
            return screenWidth / 2
        }
        override fun getPaddingEnd(): Int {
            return screenWidth / 2
        }
    }
    recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
}
```